# I get 404 Not found | Install war project in Karaf 3 from userguide

Tags: osgi, war, karaf

I can install a war but not to test it , why ????

From [Karaf tuto](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/webcontainer.html) I have done :

karaf@root()> bundle:install -s "webbundle:http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/sample.war?Bundle-SymbolicName=tomcat-sample&Web-ContextPath=/sample" 
Bundle ID: 150
karaf@root()> list |grep tom 
150 | Active |  80 | 0                    | tomcat-sample

karaf@root()>  web:list

ID  | State       | Web-State   | Level | Web-ContextPath | Name

123 | Active      | Deployed    | 80    | /sample         | tomcat-sample (0)

When I go to [http://loxcalhost:8181/sample] it's not working , why ???

Answer (score 2):

The sample war doesn't contain a welcome section in it's web.xml and therefore nothing happens if you call localhost:8181/sample you have to go for localhost:8181/sample/hello as that's the registered servlet for this web-application. 
If you issue a http:list command you'll get the following listing:

```
karaf@root()> http:list
ID  | Servlet           | Servlet-Name | State       | Alias | Url
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
103 | JspServletWrapper | jsp          | Deployed    |       | [*.jsp, *.jspx, *.jspf, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPX, *.JSPF, *.XSP]
103 | ResourceServlet   | default      | Deployed    | /     | [/]
103 |                   | HelloServlet | Deployed    |       | [/hello]
```